# Big Data (~90k) XPath Scraping

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm looking for some efficient solutions to scraping a cleaned xpath from [the Vermont Secretaty of State](http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/68156) for several thousand iterations. This is the xpath for the title that I'm trying scrape:

```
'//*[@id="content_wrapper"]/div[2]/div/h1'
```

I'm struggling in finding a clean and efficient way to run a loop that loops through approximately 90000 pages, grabs the title, and stores it in a vector. The end goal is to export a small data frame containing the page value and the title xpath. I'm going use this data frame to index future searches in the database.

This is what I've got so far:

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)

election_value <- 1:90000
title <- NA

for (i in 1:90000) {
  url <- sprintf("http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/%s", election_value[i])
  if (is.null(tryCatch({read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="content_wrapper"]/div[2]/div/h1')  %>% html_text()}, error=function(e){}))) {
    title[i] <- NA } else {
      title[i] <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="content_wrapper"]/div[2]/div/h1')}
}
vermont_titles <- data.frame(election_value, title)
write.csv(vermont_titles, 'vermont_titles.csv')
```

Unfortunately, the script doesn't work because the html_nodes() function returns the string with brackets, rather than just the text. Any solutions would be appreciated, as this script has been annoying me for a week or so.

Comment: Please check the url that you posted, "http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/%s", yields a `400 Bad request`. I think, the correct url is,  http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/search/year_from:1789/year_to:2016

Comment: the `%s` is getting substituted for a number b/c it's in a `sprintf()` call. It's still not clear what the OP is trying to do tho.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution.  See the comments for additional details:

```
library(rvest)

#url<-"http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/68156"
election_value <- 68150:68199

#predefine title vector
title <- vector("character", length=length(election_value))

for (i in 1:50) {
  url <- sprintf("http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/%s", election_value[i])
  #read page  and test if null
  page<-tryCatch({read_html(url)}, error=function(e){})
  if (is.null(page)) 
  {
      title[i] <- NA } 
  else {
    #parse the page and extract the title as text
    node<-page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="content_wrapper"]/div[2]/div/h1')
    title[i] <- node %>% html_text()
  }
}
vermont_titles <- data.frame(election_value, title)
write.csv(vermont_titles, 'vermont_titles.csv')
```

A couple of notes: Reading the page in once instead of up to twice and parsing the page only 1 time will improve performance.  Also predefining the title as a vector is another performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

Another solutions could be:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rvest)
election_value <- c(3,68150:68153)
base_url <- "http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/"
urls <- paste0(base_url, election_value)

map(urls, possibly(read_html, NA_character_)) %>% 
  map_if(negate(is.na), html_nodes, xpath = '//*[@id="content_wrapper"]/div[2]/div/h1') %>% 
  map_if(negate(is.na), html_text) %>% 
  as.character %>% 
  tibble(election_value, title = .)
```

which returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  election_value                                                 title
           <dbl>                                                 <chr>
1              3                                                    NA
2          68150    2014 Probate Judge General Election Rutland County
3          68151    2014 Probate Judge General Election Orleans County
4          68152 2014 Probate Judge General Election Grand Isle County
5          68153   2014 Probate Judge General Election Lamoille County
```